# How to resolve broken go indirect dependency?

Tags: go

As I have a project that has `github.com/datawire/ambassador@v1.14.0`, since the `ambassador` updated repo name I have changed accordingly.
Without any modification the error looks:

go mod tidy

```
go: github.com/datawire/ambassador@v1.14.0 requires
        helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.5.3 requires
        github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.10.0 requires
        github.com/docker/distribution@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

As a new go learner, I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: That import path looks broken. It shouldn't have a `/tree/master` in it, that's a GitHub URL not an import path.

Comment: @Adrian I delete my modification you are right. What does this error tell? Apparently, github.com/datawire/ambassador@v1.14.0 works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines in to go.mod file

```
replace (
    github.com/docker/distribution => github.com/docker/distribution v0.0.0-20191216044856-a8371794149d
    github.com/docker/docker => github.com/moby/moby v17.12.0-ce-rc1.0.20200618181300-9dc6525e6118+incompatible
)
```